# Why is my wireless not currently enabled on my HP Pavilion?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-driver

I have a HP Pavilion TX2000 tablet PC with me with windows 7 OS running on it. I used to access the Internet using my D-Link DIR 615 wireless adapter on the tablet and it used to work quite fine until one day, when I hibernated my Windows 7, the wireless went off and the problem seems to persist even after my hard efforts to clear it.

I checked if the router works fine, and yes it did as my iPod was still catching wireless signals on the other hand, when I checked mu device manager, I realized that I now had no wireless driver. I checked on HP's website for one, but ironically even they didn't have wireless drivers meant for my tablet for Windows 7.

Please help me find a solution to this problem.
Further queries will be entertained as frequently as possible...

Comment: Try the Vista driver from HP.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install one of the Windows XP drivers on their website using Compatibility Mode. If it doesn't work, you can always roll back or uninstall the driver.

Comment: I tried doing it with the Vista driver. Yet, it didn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Right click on My Computer.
2. Click on Properties, then click on Device Manager.
3. Connect the Computer to a Wired Network.
4. Then right click on the Driver and hit Update then "Search for drivers online".

Comment: The point is that the driver is actually not at all showing up. :(

Comment: does he hardware show up?

Answer (score 1):

You may have run into this [Nvidia overheating chipset problem](http://forum.tabletpcreview.com/hewlett-packard/announcement-warning-tx1000-2000-users-build-defect.html), which affects the tx2000 line.

See also [Warning to tx1000/2000 users](http://forum.tabletpcreview.com/hewlett-packard/27065-warning-tx1000-2000-users.html), which is referenced in that first link.